# JS API integration with Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, linkedin-jsapi

I'm using Sencha Touch to build mobile app. And my requirement is using [LinkedIn JS Api](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial) to validate the user and do operations according to the user. I'm having no problem in using the API in browser. But I have a problem when 'Sign In' button clicked, the popup window for authentication is not appeared because of Sencha Touch component didn't recognize the event or vice versa.

Any help will be appreciated.

As someone has voted it as unclear, I have added the screenshot

[image: screenshot].

The window that's asking for linked in credentials is opened in a new window of the browser and not inside the emulator which is behind the window. And i want to open the window inside the emulator not on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ripple (my theory is this is causing the problem and it is beta).

Just go to emulation in Chrome dev tools and activate emulation.

Fill in mail and password and button should work fine. :)

[image]

Comment: It's still opening in the separate window. Not inside the app.

Comment: if you want to open a new url from an application inside the application you must use 'inappbrowser' a Cordova plugin. http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Comment: but i dont think it would be that bad opening a new window, because if you want to use Cordova will have to go and make a hybrid app ... -> ST / Cordova ... that's not bad, is what I like but you have to take the time